# Rails - How to associate models in one direction only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

Ahoy guys,

I'm new to Rails, and I feel like I'm definitely missing something crucial here, because it seems like this should be an easily solvable problem.

I've set up a `Page` model and a `Coord` model (with help from the getting started tutorial), and `Coord` successfully `belongs_to` `Page`. I'm trying to apply similar logic to make another model, `Comment`, belong to `Coord`, and only belong to `Page` via `Coord`.

Do I use `:through` for an association that (I think) only needs to link in one direction? As in Page < Coord < Comment? 
At the moment I have:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  has_many :coords
  has_many :comments, :through => :coords
end
```

Coord model:

```
class Coord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :comments
  attr_accessible :coordinates, :x, :y
  validates :x, :presence => true
  validates :y, :presence => true
end
```

Then the Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coord
  belongs_to :page
  attr_accessible :body
end
```

I still keep getting errors about `comments` being an undefined method, or an association not being defined. Apologies if this is a common question, I don't personally know anyone who knows Rails, and the documentation only has examples too far removed from mine (to my knowledge). Thanks

**Edit: added DB schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120712170243) do

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "coord_id"
    t.integer  "page_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["coord_id"], :name => "index_comments_on_coord_id"
  add_index "comments", ["page_id"], :name => "index_comments_on_page_id"

  create_table "coords", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "coordinates"
    t.integer  "x"
    t.integer  "y"
    t.integer  "page_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  add_index "coords", ["page_id"], :name => "index_coords_on_page_id"

  create_table "pages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

end
```

Comment: has_one  :coord ,:through => :page should work in your case

Comment: wouldn't you need to have a coord_id:integer in the Comment model so that it can reference a Comment to a Coord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :coords
  has_many :comments, :through => :coords
end
```

**Coord**

```
class Coord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :comments
end
```

**Comment**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coord
  has_one :page, :through => :coord
end
```

Using the above, you don't need `page_id` in the `comments` table.

**Reference:** [*A Guide to Active Record Associations*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)